# Outlook VBA Save Attachment is saving wrong attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I've been struggling with this for quite some time now, I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

I've got a script that will loop through emails in a folder.  Then it checks the first 6 characters of the email subject.  If it matches it must call a sub that will save the attachment to a specific folder, the only thing is that the file name changes every time depending on the subject of the email.  Everything works fine if there is only 1 email in the folder, but as soon as there is more than 1 email it saves the last email attachment everytime but with the correct file name.  So for example if you look at the underneath code it will save the attachment from `ElseIf strLeft = "APPPE2" Then` everytime with the filenames specified, eg report1.txt ... Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Function LoopThroughFolder()

Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.GetFirst ' folders of your current account
Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox").Folders("PPB")

For Each Item In objFolder.Items
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        ' ... do stuff here ...
        Set Msg = Item
        Dim strSubject As String
        strSubject = Item.Subject
        Dim strLeft As String
        strLeft = Left(strSubject, 6)

        If strLeft = "APP DA" Then
            Call SaveAttachments1
        ElseIf strLeft = "APPGR1" Then
            Call SaveAttachments2
        ElseIf strLeft = "APPPE2" Then
            Call SaveAttachments3
        End If

    End If
Next

End Function

Public Sub SaveAttachments1()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile1 As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String

    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    strFolderpath = "P:\database\"

    For Each objMsg In objSelection

    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count

    If lngCount > 0 Then

    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

    strFile1 = "report.txt"
    MsgBox (strFile1)


    strFile1 = strFolderpath & strFile1
    MsgBox (strFile1)

    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile1

    Next i
    End If

    Next

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub SaveAttachments2()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile2 As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    strFolderpath = "P:\database\"

    For Each objMsg In objSelection

    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count

    If lngCount > 0 Then

    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

    strFile2 = "report2.txt"
    MsgBox (strFile2)

    strFile2 = strFolderpath & strFile2
    MsgBox (strFile2)
    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile2

    Next i
    End If

    Next

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
Public Sub SaveAttachments3()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile3 As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    strFolderpath = "P:\database\"

    For Each objMsg In objSelection

    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count

    If lngCount > 0 Then       

    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

    strFile3 = "report3.txt"

    strFile3 = strFolderpath & strFile3

    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile3

    Next i
    End If

    Next

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to step through the code using `F8` you may find the error doing so?

Comment: Hi sorry only saw your comment now, I think the problem is it is not selecting the current mail .... I don't know how ... I will try the F8 option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your `SaveAttachments` subs should have a `objMsg` parameter, which should be passed from `LoopThroughFolder` - there is no need to "re-find" the message just to save the attachments.

Untested but something like this:

```
Function LoopThroughFolder()

    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace, Item, Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.GetFirst ' folders of your current account
    Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox").Folders("PPB")

    For Each Item In objFolder.Items
        If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
            ' ... do stuff here ...
            Set Msg = Item
            Dim strSubject As String
            strSubject = Msg.Subject
            Dim strLeft As String
            strLeft = Left(strSubject, 6)

            If strLeft = "APP DA" Then
                SaveAttachments1 Msg
            ElseIf strLeft = "APPGR1" Then
                SaveAttachments2 Msg
            ElseIf strLeft = "APPPE2" Then
                SaveAttachments3 Msg
            End If

        End If
    Next

End Function

Public Sub SaveAttachments1(objMsg As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long

    Dim strFolderpath As String

    strFolderpath = "P:\database\"
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count

    If lngCount > 0 Then
    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
        objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFolderpath & "report.txt"
    Next i
    End If

End Sub
```